# Given two strings, determine if they share a common substring

Tags: java

This is my first Question here, I need to know why the following code does not pass Sample test case 2 in hacker rank-> Algorithms-> Strings-> Two Strings:
The question is here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/two-strings/problem

```
public static String twoStrings(String s1, String s2) {
        String answer = ""; 
        String StringToIterate = "";
        String theOtherString = "";
    
        if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
            StringToIterate = s2;
            theOtherString  = s1;
        } else if (s1.length() < s2.length()){
            StringToIterate = s1;
            theOtherString = s2;
        } else {
            StringToIterate = s1;
            theOtherString = s2;
        }
    
    for (int i= 0; i < StringToIterate.length();i++) {
         String subS = StringToIterate.substring(i);
         if (theOtherString.contains(subS)) {
            answer = "YES";
        } else {
            answer = "NO";
       }
   }
   return answer;
   }
}
```

Sample test case 2:
2

```
aardvark

apple

beetroot

sandals
```

my code gives: No No
but the expected output is: Yes No

Comment: You are overwriting `answer` on every iteration of your `for` loop. So `answer` will always be the value of the last iteration. It would probably be fixed by adding a `break` after determining that `answer` should be `"YES"`.

Comment: I added the break; after "YES", IT does not work.

Comment: Could you please edit the question to include _what the code should actually do_?

Comment: Why don't you just `return "YES";` ? That way you don't need the answer variable, nor overwrite it I don't know how many times with "NO" and you can just `return "NO"; ` When the for-loop ends. You also don't need `StringToIterate` or `theOtherString`, you can just use the params. And the second and third block of your if else do exactly the same...

Comment: `.substring(i)` will return a substring *starting at* position `i`. The question at Hacker Rank indicates that the function should return "YES" even if a single letter matches. The quickest fix would be to change it to use `.substring(i, i+1)` to make sure you only check if `theOtherString` contains a single letter from `StringToIterate` (you'll still need the `break` or early `return` as suggested by @H3AR7B3A7).

Comment: yes, you are right, problem solved by both: adding break; after "YES" ,and using .substring(i, i+1), thanks

Comment: now I got Time limit exceeded, for 2 other test cases, when I tried to submit the code.

Comment: Please add the solution in the answer space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming one of the test cases uses a fairly large string with a lot of duplicate letters. You can try editing your solution to keep track of substrings you've already checked. For example:

```
public static String twoStrings(String s1, String s2) {
    String answer = ""; 
    String StringToIterate = "";
    String theOtherString = "";

    List<String> checked = new ArrayList<>();

    if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
        StringToIterate = s2;
        theOtherString  = s1;
    } else if (s1.length() < s2.length()){
        StringToIterate = s1;
        theOtherString = s2;
    } else {
        StringToIterate = s1;
        theOtherString = s2;
    }

    for (int i= 0; i < StringToIterate.length();i++) {
        String subS = StringToIterate.substring(i,i+1);
        if (checked.contains(subS)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (theOtherString.contains(subS)) {
            answer = "YES";
            break;
        } else {
            checked.add(subS);
            answer = "NO";
        }
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Running your function with the `checked` List does not run into the time limit.

But this got me thinking "a Stream can do *all of this*" and that had me solving this problem in a completely different manner:

```
public static String twoStrings(String s1, String s2) {
    return s1.chars()
             .distinct()
             .mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char)c))
             .anyMatch(s2::contains) ? "YES" : "NO";
}
```

Without the `.distinct()` step I also get a timeout on tests 4 and 5, but with it all tests pass reasonably quickly.

Answer (score 0):

To get this sample case working I would suggest replacing `answer = "YES";` with `return "YES";`.

There only has to be one substring that matches. Therefore, you should stop searching when you have found a match.
Your code will happily continue searching through other substrings, even if you already found a match, and thereby setting the `answer` back to `NO`.

I don't know what the exact assignment was, but it seems that you also have to look at internal substrings. Your code only looks at the first i letters of `StringToIterate`.

I try to explain it using your sample case:
Your code will substring check these strings

```
a
ap
app
appl
apple
```

However, `p` or `le` could've also been substrings of aardvark.
Try to change your code to also check these substrings.

I hope this is enough information to keep on coding and good luck with your assignment!

Comment: OP's code only looks at **the last** `n` letters, not the first `i` letters.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved and The initial Test cases passed by doing the suggestions given by the commenters:adding break; after "YES" and use substring(i,i+1). However, when I submitted the code after suggested corrections, I got "Time limit exceeded" problem.

```
public static String twoStrings(String s1, String s2) {
        String answer = ""; 
        String StringToIterate = "";
        String theOtherString = "";

        if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
            StringToIterate = s2;
            theOtherString  = s1;
        } else if (s1.length() < s2.length()){
            StringToIterate = s1;
            theOtherString = s2;
        } else {
            StringToIterate = s1;
            theOtherString = s2;
        }

    for (int i= 0; i < StringToIterate.length();i++) {
         String subS = StringToIterate.substring(i,i+1);
         if (theOtherString.contains(subS)) {
            answer = "YES";
            break;
        } else {
            answer = "NO";
       }
   }
   return answer;
   }
}
```

Also, I cannot add return inside the for loop/if statement,because the compiler of course wants a return in the method body but outside the for loop. So, any suggestion?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with just `for loop` which beats the time requirement.
This loops from a to z using their ASCII code. ie. 97 - 122, converts the code to a character and checks if both strings contain any of the character

```
public static String twoStrings(String s1, String s2) {     
    for(int i = 97; i <= 122; i++){
        char c = (char) i;
        if(s1.contains(""+c) && s2.contains(""+c)){
            return "YES";
        }
    }
    return "NO";
    }

}
```